# matplotlib rearranging bars when plotting from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a barplot from a dictionary using matplotlib but it seems to be rearranging the bars. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import string

char_dict = {}

for char in string.lowercase:
    char_dict[char] = char_dict.get(char, 0) + np.random.randint(1, 10)

plt.bar(range(len(char_dict)), char_dict.values(), align = 'center')
_ = plt.xticks(range(len(char_dict)), char_dict.keys())
plt.margins(0.05, 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `dict` if you want the values to be sorted, the return can be completly random.

There is `OrderedDict` (in the collections-library) which is basically a sorted dict. And looks/works exactly the same.

Or you can use two lists one for the keys and one for the values.

Answer (score 1):

Python dicts are not ordered:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items says

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

To fix this, you should use collections.OrderedDict to store your data: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Answer (score 1):

Normal dictionaries do not have an order. You could use an [Ordered dictionary](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html). Or sort the results before you plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_str = 'testdstasdtaetsts'

char_dict = {}

for char in input_str.lower():
    char_dict[char] = char_dict.get(char, 0) + np.random.randint(1, 10)

result_list = sorted([[chars, counts] for chars, counts in char_dict.items()], key = lambda x: x[0])

characters = [x[0] for x in result_list]
counts = [x[1] for x in result_list]

plt.bar(range(len(char_dict)), counts, align = 'center')
_ = plt.xticks(range(len(char_dict)), characters)
plt.margins(0.05, 0)

plt.show()
```